# Distributed Tensorflow: non-chief worker blocked

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed

I am trying the distributed tensorflow, and my code is shown as follow. The problem is that the chief worker can run as expected. However, non-chief worker will blocked at :

> sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(target, config=sess_config)

Could anybody help me solve this problem?

```
  # Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
  #
  # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  # you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  # You may obtain a copy of the License at
  #
  #     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  #
  # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  # limitations under the License.
  # ==============================================================================
  """A library to train Inception using multiple replicas with synchronous update.

  Please see accompanying README.md for details and instructions.
  """
  from __future__ import absolute_import
  from __future__ import division
  from __future__ import print_function

  from datetime import datetime
  import os.path
  import time

  import numpy as np
  import tensorflow as tf

  from inception.slim.datasets import dataset_factory
  from inception.slim.nets import nets_factory
  from inception.slim.preprocessing import preprocessing_factory
  from inception import inception_model as inception
  from inception.slim import slim
  #from inception import image_processing
  sslim = tf.contrib.slim
  FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
  'dataset_name', 'imagenet', 'The name of the dataset to load.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
  'dataset_split_name', 'train', 'The name of the train/test split.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
  'train_image_size', None, 'Train image size')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
  'dataset_dir', None, 'The directory where the dataset files are stored.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('job_name', '', 'One of "ps", "worker"')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('ps_hosts', '',
                         """Comma-separated list of hostname:port for the """
                         """parameter server jobs. e.g. """
                         """'machine1:2222,machine2:1111,machine2:2222'""")
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('worker_hosts', '',
                         """Comma-separated list of hostname:port for the """
                         """worker jobs. e.g. """
                         """'machine1:2222,machine2:1111,machine2:2222'""")
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float(
  'weight_decay', 0.00004, 'The weight decay on the model weights.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', '/tmp/imagenet_train',
                         """Directory where to write event logs """
                         """and checkpoint.""")
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('max_steps', 100, 'Number of batches to run.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('subset', 'train', 'Either "train" or "validation".')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_boolean('log_device_placement', False,
                          'Whether to log device placement.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
  'model_name', 'inception_v3', 'The name of the architecture to train.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
  'batch_size', 32, 'The number of samples in each batch.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string(
  'preprocessing_name', None, 'The name of the preprocessing to use. If left '
  'as `None`, then the model_name flag is used.')
  # Task ID is used to select the chief and also to access the local_step for
  # each replica to check staleness of the gradients in sync_replicas_optimizer.
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer(
  'task_id', 0, 'Task ID of the worker/replica running the training.')

  # More details can be found in the sync_replicas_optimizer class:
  # tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_replicas_to_aggregate', -1,
                          """Number of gradients to collect before """
                          """updating the parameters.""")
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('save_interval_secs', 10 * 60,
                          'Save interval seconds.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('save_summaries_secs', 10 * 60,
                          'Save summaries interval seconds.')

  # **IMPORTANT**
  # Please note that this learning rate schedule is heavily dependent on the
  # hardware architecture, batch size and any changes to the model architecture
  # specification. Selecting a finely tuned learning rate schedule is an
  # empirical process that requires some experimentation. Please see README.md
  # more guidance and discussion.
  #
  # Learning rate decay factor selected from https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00981
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float('initial_learning_rate', 0.045,
                        'Initial learning rate.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float('num_epochs_per_decay', 2.0,
                        'Epochs after which learning rate decays.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate_decay_factor', 0.94,
                        'Learning rate decay factor.')

  # Constants dictating the learning rate schedule.
  RMSPROP_DECAY = 0.9                # Decay term for RMSProp.
  RMSPROP_MOMENTUM = 0.9             # Momentum in RMSProp.
  RMSPROP_EPSILON = 1.0              # Epsilon term for RMSProp.


  def train(target, dataset, cluster_spec):
  """Train Inception on a dataset for a number of steps."""
  # Number of workers and parameter servers are infered from the workers and ps
  # hosts string.
  num_workers = len(cluster_spec.as_dict()['worker'])
  num_parameter_servers = len(cluster_spec.as_dict()['ps'])
  # If no value is given, num_replicas_to_aggregate defaults to be the number of
  # workers.
  if FLAGS.num_replicas_to_aggregate == -1:
  num_replicas_to_aggregate = num_workers
  else:
  num_replicas_to_aggregate = FLAGS.num_replicas_to_aggregate

  # Both should be greater than 0 in a distributed training.
  assert num_workers > 0 and num_parameter_servers > 0, (' num_workers and '
                                                       'num_parameter_servers'
                                                       ' must be > 0.')

  # Choose worker 0 as the chief. Note that any worker could be the chief
  # but there should be only one chief.
  is_chief = (FLAGS.task_id == 0)
  # Ops are assigned to worker by default.
  with tf.device('/job:worker/task:%d' % FLAGS.task_id):
  # Variables and its related init/assign ops are assigned to ps.
  with slim.scopes.arg_scope(
      [slim.variables.variable, slim.variables.global_step],
      device=slim.variables.VariableDeviceChooser(num_parameter_servers)):
    # Create a variable to count the number of train() calls. This equals the
    # number of updates applied to the variables.
    global_step = slim.variables.global_step()

    # Calculate the learning rate schedule.
    num_batches_per_epoch = (dataset.num_examples_per_epoch() /
                             FLAGS.batch_size)
    # Decay steps need to be divided by the number of replicas to aggregate.
    decay_steps = int(num_batches_per_epoch * FLAGS.num_epochs_per_decay /
                      num_replicas_to_aggregate)

    # Decay the learning rate exponentially based on the number of steps.
    lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(FLAGS.initial_learning_rate,
                                    global_step,
                                    decay_steps,
                                    FLAGS.learning_rate_decay_factor,
                                    staircase=True)
    # Add a summary to track the learning rate.
    tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', lr)

    # Create an optimizer that performs gradient descent.
    opt = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(lr,
                                    RMSPROP_DECAY,
                                    momentum=RMSPROP_MOMENTUM,
                                    epsilon=RMSPROP_EPSILON)

    dataset = dataset_factory.get_dataset(
      FLAGS.dataset_name, FLAGS.dataset_split_name, FLAGS.dataset_dir)
    network_fn = nets_factory.get_network_fn(
      FLAGS.model_name,
      num_classes=(dataset.num_classes),
      weight_decay=FLAGS.weight_decay,
      is_training=True)
    preprocessing_name = FLAGS.preprocessing_name or FLAGS.model_name
    image_preprocessing_fn = preprocessing_factory.get_preprocessing(
      preprocessing_name,
      is_training=True)
    provider = sslim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(
        dataset,
        num_readers=4,
        common_queue_capacity=20 * FLAGS.batch_size,
        common_queue_min=10 * FLAGS.batch_size)
    [image, label] = provider.get(['image', 'label'])
    train_image_size = FLAGS.train_image_size or network_fn.default_image_size

    image = image_preprocessing_fn(image, train_image_size, train_image_size)

    images, labels = tf.train.batch(
        [image, label],
        batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
        num_threads=4,
        capacity=5 * FLAGS.batch_size)
    # Number of classes in the Dataset label set plus 1.
    # Label 0 is reserved for an (unused) background class.
    num_classes = 1001

    logits, end_points = network_fn(images)
    batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size
    # Add classification loss.
    sparse_labels = tf.reshape(labels, [batch_size, 1])
    indices = tf.reshape(tf.range(batch_size), [batch_size, 1])
    #concated = tf.concat(1, [indices, sparse_labels])
    sparse_labels = tf.cast(sparse_labels, tf.int32)
    concated = tf.concat([indices, sparse_labels], 1)
    dense_labels = tf.sparse_to_dense(concated,
                                  [batch_size, 1001],
                                  1.0, 0.0) 
    slim.losses.cross_entropy_loss(
        logits, dense_labels, label_smoothing=0.01, weight=1.0)
    # Gather all of the losses including regularization losses.
    losses = tf.get_collection(slim.losses.LOSSES_COLLECTION)
    losses += tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)

    total_loss = tf.add_n(losses, name='total_loss')

    if is_chief:
      # Compute the moving average of all individual losses and the
      # total loss.
      loss_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9, name='avg')
      loss_averages_op = loss_averages.apply(losses + [total_loss])

      # Attach a scalar summmary to all individual losses and the total loss;
      # do the same for the averaged version of the losses.
      for l in losses + [total_loss]:
        loss_name = l.op.name
        # Name each loss as '(raw)' and name the moving average version of the
        # loss as the original loss name.
        tf.summary.scalar(loss_name + '_raw', l)
        tf.summary.scalar(loss_name, loss_averages.average(l))

      # Add dependency to compute loss_averages.
      with tf.control_dependencies([loss_averages_op]):
        total_loss = tf.identity(total_loss)

    # Track the moving averages of all trainable variables.
    # Note that we maintain a 'double-average' of the BatchNormalization
    # global statistics.
    # This is not needed when the number of replicas are small but important
    # for synchronous distributed training with tens of workers/replicas.
    exp_moving_averager = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(
        inception.MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY, global_step)

    variables_to_average = (
        tf.trainable_variables() + tf.moving_average_variables())

    # Add histograms for model variables.
    for var in variables_to_average:
      tf.summary.histogram(var.op.name, var)

    # Create synchronous replica optimizer.
    opt = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(
        opt,
        replicas_to_aggregate=num_replicas_to_aggregate,
        total_num_replicas=num_workers,
        variable_averages=exp_moving_averager,
        variables_to_average=variables_to_average)

    # Compute gradients with respect to the loss.
    grads = opt.compute_gradients(total_loss)

    # Add histograms for gradients.
    for grad, var in grads:
      if grad is not None:
        tf.summary.histogram(var.op.name + '/gradients', grad)

    apply_gradients_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)

    with tf.control_dependencies([apply_gradients_op]):
      train_op = tf.identity(total_loss, name='train_op')

    # Get chief queue_runners, init_tokens and clean_up_op, which is used to
    # synchronize replicas.
    # More details can be found in sync_replicas_optimizer.
    chief_queue_runners = [opt.get_chief_queue_runner()]
    init_tokens_op = opt.get_init_tokens_op()

    # Build the summary operation based on the TF collection of Summaries.
    summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

    # Build an initialization operation to run below.
    #init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # We run the summaries in the same thread as the training operations by
    # passing in None for summary_op to avoid a summary_thread being started.
    # Running summaries and training operations in parallel could run out of
    # GPU memory.

    sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=is_chief,
                             logdir=FLAGS.train_dir,
                             init_op=init_op,
                             summary_op=None,
                             global_step=global_step,
                             #saver=saver,
                             saver=None,
                             save_model_secs=FLAGS.save_interval_secs)

    tf.logging.info('%s Supervisor' % datetime.now())

    sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(
        allow_soft_placement=True,
        log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement)
    # Get a session.
    sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(target, config=sess_config)
    # Start the queue runners.
    queue_runners = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS)
    sv.start_queue_runners(sess, queue_runners)
    tf.logging.info('Started %d queues for processing input data.',
                  len(queue_runners))
    if is_chief:
      sv.start_queue_runners(sess, chief_queue_runners)
      sess.run(init_tokens_op)

    # Train, checking for Nans. Concurrently run the summary operation at a
    # specified interval. Note that the summary_op and train_op never run
    # simultaneously in order to prevent running out of GPU memory.
    #sess = sv.managed_session(target)
    next_summary_time = time.time() + FLAGS.save_summaries_secs
    while not sv.should_stop():
      try:
        start_time = time.time()
        loss_value, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step])
        assert not np.isnan(loss_value), 'Model diverged with loss = NaN'
        if step > FLAGS.max_steps: 
          break
        duration = time.time() - start_time
        if step % 10 == 0:
          examples_per_sec = FLAGS.batch_size / float(duration)
          format_str = ('Worker %d: %s: step %d, loss = %.2f'
                        '(%.1f examples/sec; %.3f  sec/batch)')
          tf.logging.info(format_str %
                          (FLAGS.task_id, datetime.now(), step, loss_value,
                           examples_per_sec, duration))

        # Determine if the summary_op should be run on the chief worker.
        if is_chief and next_summary_time < time.time():
          tf.logging.info('Running Summary operation on the chief.')
          summary_str = sess.run(summary_op)
          sv.summary_computed(sess, summary_str)
          tf.logging.info('Finished running Summary operation.')

          # Determine the next time for running the summary.
          next_summary_time += FLAGS.save_summaries_secs 
      except:
        if is_chief:
          tf.logging.info('About to execute sync_clean_up_op!')
          #sess.run(clean_up_op)
        raise

    # Stop the supervisor.  This also waits for service threads to finish.
    sv.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sync will create a local variable which will basically create the local step variable which is a local variable. But VariableDeviceChooser doesn't tell global from local so it is not functioning until we fix the device chooser. Thanks for reporting though.

Comment: But I see that there is the same usage of VariableDeviceChooser in this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py). I have ran the program and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Also concerned about this issue，Can you put your command line here?

Comment: You can visit [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1374) to join the issue discussion.